# T-network feedback of op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, transimpedance

I want to know how the equivalent resistance of T network feedback in this op amp configuration is calculated?

[image]

Comment: It seems that something is missing ... A resistor between CH1 and the input- of the op-amp.

Comment: The AD711 **WILL NOT** work on a single supply of 5 volts. A precise schematic is needed. Minimum supply is +/- 5 volts.

Comment: @Antonio51 since it's tagged "transimpedance" I guess CH1 is a current input

Comment: This is a transimpedance amplifier @Antonio51

Comment: The input to the opamp is from a hydrophone

Comment: @user253751 Sorry ... Did not take "attention" at "tag".

Answer (score 0):

> T-network feedback of op amp

If interested by the frequency behavior ... (EE&O).
Curves are op-amp OL (~ AD711), v4 (Go & a, into account), and Vo (infinite opamp gain).

[image]